# Can I do Push Notification " Alerts " In Mac

Tags: macos, alerts

Actually I am Noob For Mac Development, And I need To make an Alert Like This

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5paS.png

This is for DropBox App . And It appears in the Upper Right Corner ...

Actually I do not Know Its Name , So I can not create it !!

If Any One Has a good reference for this Object , I will be appreciated

Thanks,

Ghalab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DropBox uses Growl Framework

http://growl.info/

Comment: But Do I Have To Install The Growl App In The Mac That Will Use My Program .. To run this feature in his device .. Or It will work universally without this problem ...

Comment: Growl is a third party framework, so will have to install it on the system

Comment: there a write up on growl web site http://goo.gl/Pq4bq if you are planning on distributing Growl you can just package it with your Metapackage installer, have a look at Apple Packagemaker documentation http://goo.gl/n54TL